# Two inline threads from the main class in Java belong to same object?

Tags: java, concurrency

In the code below do threads t1 and t2 belong to the same object? if yes? which object.  Will they compete to acquire monitor or mutex lock?

If they belong to the different objects. How? An explanation in terms of monitors would be useful.

```
package com.java.thread.practice;

public class InlineObject_SameThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

            // Will this compete with thread t2 to acquire monitor ??   

            }

        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Will this compete with thread t1 to acquire monitor ??   

            }

        });

        // Starting the first thread.

        t1.start();

        // Starting the second thread.

        t2.start();

        /* There can be further logic, currently I will placing those as
         * we progress.
         */ 
    }

    /*
      Code ends.
    */

}
```

Comment: Threads (or objects in general) don't belong to other objects. Other objects may have a *reference* to those threads, but that's not ownership, any more than somebody who knows my phone number would own my phone.

Comment: I removed _"I am looking for a discussion"_ from your post.  StackOverflow is explicitly NOT for discussions.  Also, please pay attention to the other format changes I made, and learn how to format your post and code.

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner.

Does that mean both thread refer to same object 'this(InlineObject_SameThread )' ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly; but if you refer to `this` inside the bodies of the two `Runnable`s, they will refer to different `Runnable`s.

Answer (score 0):

> do threads t1 and t2 belong to the same object?

Threads do not *belong to* objects, nor do objects belong to other objects.  Objects may hold *references* to other objects, including `Thread` objects representing threads.  Being a bit pedantic, the references do not belong to objects, either -- they are just values.  No object can own a reference any more than it can own the value 1.  Objects may own *variables* in which references are stored.

> Will they compete to acquire monitor or mutex lock?

Everything else notwithstanding, threads do not acquire objects' monitors without reason.  In your example, neither thread does anything that would cause it to attempt to acquire any object's monitor.  Certainly such threads could be made to do work that caused them to contend for the same monitor, but that has little to do with them being "inline" as you call it.

> If they belong to the different objects. How? An explanation in terms of monitors would be useful.

Each `Thread` object represents a thread, whose existence is substantially independent of the context in which the thread was created.  However, only `main()` has a reference to either one.  There is no explanation in terms of monitors, because monitors don't factor in at all.

Furthermore, the code executing in `main()` is not associated with any object because `main()` is `static`. There isn't any object for the threads to belong to, other than themselves.  The two `Runnable()` instances exist, but there's no justification for asserting that the `Thread`s belong to those.  If anything, you might argue that it's the other way around.

Comment: Thanks. The information is useful and clears the doubt.